# Calling java method from jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am calling my java method from jsp its giving `NoClassDefFoundError: error`.

But my method is working when i am calling from the `main` method. 
 i have used `xlrd` jar in my code and i have placed the jar lib folder as well. but still it gives error.

***Exception trace***:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /exportDSD.jsp at line 20

17:     //excel.getExcel();
18:     
19:     Report r = new Report();
20:     r.generateReport();
21:     
22:     System.out.println("Generated DSD");
23: %>
```

***Stacktrace***:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

***root cause*** :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xlrd/Workbook
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.exportDSD_jsp._jspService(exportDSD_jsp.java:107)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My code :

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell; 
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle; 
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat; 
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow; 
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet; 
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
 import xlrd.*;

 public void generateReport() throws BiffException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException { 
 ... ... 
 }
```

From jsp i am calling like this:

```
<% Report r =new Report(); r.generateReport(); %>
```

Comment: Here is my code:

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import xlrd.*;

public void generateReport() throws BiffException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException

{

...
...

}

From jsp i am calling like this:

<%
Report r =new Report();
r.generateReport();

%>

Comment: Please add the code to your question using the edit function. Not as a comment.

Comment: I cannot read you code. post it in ques (formatted)

Comment: Share your jsp code...may be imports not correct

Comment: These are my imports in jsp
<%@ page language="java" import = "com.sample.Report"%>
<%@ page language="java" import = "xlrd.*"%>

Comment: That's incorrect. See answer.

Answer (score 4):

Appears JSP import not correct:

```
Add jar in WEB-INF/lib
Add <%@ page import="xlrd.*" %> to the top of your JSP
```

To import more than one classes, use the following format:

```
<%@ page import="com.sample.Report,xlrd.*" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with jar containing Workbook in some jar. Put it in the WEB-INF/lib folder. I don't think, this need to be included in the JSP as well.

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is a JVM Error which means that JVM or class loader was not able to **load the class definition**.  This means that class was found but due to some reason JVM or class loader was not able to **load** the class definition.
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xlrd/Workbook` doesn't mean that class was not found, if that was the case you would have got `ClassNotFoundException`. On contrary, class file was found but JVM is unable to load the class definition.

For `NoClassDefFoundError` you can check source of `xlrd/Workbook` if it contains some static block or member which is referencing some class which is not present or causing issue at runtime.